# SDK Version Issue

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

i'm getting the Warning when i upload my application through xcode 8.x.

> Xcode for future app deliveries." WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version
>   Issue. In July 2018, iOS app updates submitted to the App Store will
>   need to be built with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode
>   [9.0] or later. Make sure to update Xcode for future app deliveries."

My project was developed in old swift 2.X language and some of the module in objective-c..

should i convert whole project to the latest swift 4.x and update all sdks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in July, all app updates and all new apps submitted to the App Store must be created with a Base SDK of iOS 11.0 or later. This requires Xcode 9.0 or later. This means your app must be in Swift 4 or later. You may still support earlier versions of iOS (either 8 or 9) in your app.

Swift 2 has been obsolete for a few years already.

So yes, you need to convert to Swift 4 and update any libraries you may be using accordingly. Use Xcode 8 to first convert your Swift 2 code to Swift 3 (huge change). Then use Xcode 9 to convert the Swift 3 code to Swift 4 (minor changes).

Apple wants you using the latest tools. You need to keep up. It's best to avoid waiting until cutoffs like this, it just makes updating your app that much harder.

Comment: Do any Apple Insiders know the exact date of this change? This actually makes older versions of Macs obsolete for development, since we can't update our OS beyond 10.11. I think XCode9 requires 10.12. I am scrambling to try to get a final version uploaded before my computer turns to a pumpkin, but it would be nice to know the exact date at which this will happen.

Comment: See what Apple has to say: https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/ It just says "*Starting July 2018*".

Comment: I guess that means July 1 then.. 3 days from now!

Comment: @rmaddy what we do if our code in objective-c and successfully running in xcode 9 ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha The language is irrelevant. You need to build for iOS 11 or later with Xcode 9. And soon it may be iOS 12 and Xcode 10.

Comment: is an existing app on App Store is affected with this issue??

Comment: @RajAggrawal There are apps built with Xcode 4 still on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you update your code to swift 4.

First, they said April, and how that deadline absolutely positively included updates. Then the general lever wasn't actually pulled until right after May 1. Now they say July for updates...

Seems to be a moving target. That, and how the left hand is out walking the dog while the right hand is texting about the new red phone.