# Does Xcode 7.3.1 run on High sierra 10.13.6

Tags: ios, xcode7, macos-high-sierra

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 with HighSierra10.12.6 and now I need Xcode 9.4.1 too for a project so I have to Update my macOS to HighSierra10.13.6.
so here my Question is-
will Xcode7.3.1 work fine on updated HighSierra10.13.6 or not?

Comment: May be but useless now, because Appstore is also accepting build only with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later. 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/50570512/6898523

Comment: yupp I had to use updated OS